# Django Autocomplete form media tag problem

Tags: django, django-templates, django-autocomplete-light

in my html file i use `{{ form.media }}` tag but not see included `JavaScript` files in chrome browser

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{# Don't forget that one ! #}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>

{{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Can someone help me ?

Comment: If You have the ´static´ path defined in your ´settings.py´ file, I don't see why you add all the path on your template, what if you 1.- Check the path on your settings.py file 2.- Just declare it as ´{% static 'jquery.js' %}´ ? You can also load the Jquery file from a CDN, just saying

Comment: Try cleaning browser cache.